# Converting a string to dictionary in Python Value Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried different options to convert a string to dictionary.

My string looks like this:

```
{'severity_label': 'Major', 'ne_reported_time': 1475424546, 'node_id': 54357, 'prob_cause_string': None}
```

When i use

```
 a_dict = dict([x.strip('{}').split(":"),])
```

it gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#168>", line 1, in <module>
    a_dict = dict([x.strip('{}').split(":"),])
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 121; 2 is required
```

I am running this on Python3. Also tried various other options things not working. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You got the right answer (using `ast.literal_eval()`) but you should really consider why you have a Python dictionary string representation in the first place. That is not a sane format to pass around information. Better use JSON or any other _standard_ format. Or at least pickled data, as that is meant to be a serialization format.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is not JSON. This is a representation of a python object (like using the `repr` function).

The most safe way to convert this back to a python object is to use the `ast.literal_eval` function.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use Python 3's inbuilt **ast** library's function **literal_eval**. It is better to use **literal_eval** instead of eval

```
import ast
str_of_dict = "{'key1': 'key1value', 'key2': 'key2value'}"
ast.literal_eval(str_of_dict)
```

will give output as **actual Dictionary**

```
{'key1': 'key1value', 'key2': 'key2value'}
```

This is easy as you like.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **json.loads**

```
import json
a = '{"severity_label": "Major", "ne_reported_time": 1475424546, "node_id": 54357, "prob_cause_string": null}'
d = json.loads(a)
```

Note I replaced ' by " and None by null

Answer (score -1):

That string really is valid JSON, I think. Just use the `json.loads` functionality to get a dictionary.